# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method - Google Sheets API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I am writing a script to pass up a list into Google Sheets to append to a sheet already created. I have already ran the sample code from the Google Sheets API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python). Most of my code makes sense to me (see below), but I haven't worked with JSON file formats, and I think the way I am formatting the row being appended is what's triggering the error:

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or `None` or have an `__index__` method

This is what is trying to be passed through from the list into the Google Sheet:

```
['2018-09-24', '6.16% to 35.89%', '6.99% to 24.99%', '6.99% to 24.99%']
```

This code below does the following:

1. Scrapes several sites
2. Stores the info in a pandas dataframe
3. Convert that dataframe to a list
4. Pass that list through the Google Sheets API and append it to the sheet. (**The error is most being caused here because this is where the list is being read and trying to be passed into the Google Sheet**)

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[], 'Link':[], 'APR Rate':[]})
#cycle through links in array until it finds APR rates/fixed or variable using regex
for link in plcompetitors:
    cdate = datetime.date.today()
    sdate = str(cdate)
    l = r.get(link)
    l.encoding = 'utf-8'
    data = l.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
    for n in paragraph:
        matches = re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string)
        try:
            irate = str(matches[0])
            df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[cdate], 'Link':[link], 'APR Rate':[irate]})
            df = pd.concat([df, df2], join="inner")
            df.drop_duplicates(subset='Link', keep='first', inplace=True)
            s1 = df['APR Rate'].values.tolist()
            s1.insert(0, sdate)
        except IndexError:
            pass
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
def main():
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    spreadsheet_id = '1vk5uZQ-nJgTURH6P9Gq0QyyixsMN8e8hionS_ucko2g'
    range_ = "'Personal Loan'!B1:D"
    value_input_option = 'RAW'
    value_range_body = {
        "majorDimensions": "ROWS"
        ["values":
            s1
        ]
    }
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_,
                                                 valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)
    response = request.execute()
    pprint(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Provide examples of your various components of the update request. Also, highlight the line on which the error is issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of several things that was wrong. Definitely a valuable learning experience.

This these 3 lines updated the JSON payload so that the Google Sheets API could read it:

```
u1 = ",".join(item for item in s1)
value = u1.strip().split(",")
value.insert(0,sdate)
```

I basically took s1 from above and turned it into a comma separated list and inserted the date I wanted sent to the spreadsheet.

Then I had to delete and reauthenticate the token.json file by running the quickstart.py sample from the Google Sheets API documentation. Then I had to update the variables for the request body below and got it to work:

```
range_ = "A1:D1"
value_input_option = 'RAW'
insert_data_option = 'INSERT_ROWS'
value_range_body = {
     "majorDimension": "ROWS",
     "values": [value],
}
request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                                                 range=range_,
                                                 valueInputOption=value_input_option,
                                                 insertDataOption=insert_data_option,
                                                 body=value_range_body)
```

My main hurdle here was understanding JSON formatting, and the Sheets API was a bit confusing. Hopefully this post will help clear some confusion up for someone else as well.